# Customize face foreground color value using the color of another face

Tags: org-mode, faces, colors

I am making some small customizations to my `org-agenda` view.

For the face called "Org Agenda Done", I am adding a strikethrough and changing the color.

The color I want to use is already defined as the foreground color for "Org Agenda Dimmed Todo Face".

Is there a way to define the color of "Org Agenda Done" using the value of "Org Agenda Dimmed Todo Face"?

Right now, I only see the option to define the color of the face with a hex value.

[image]

Comment: You could inherit from the other face, and add your own properties. (However, if the other face defines a lot of extra attributes besides the foreground face this doesn't work.)

Comment: @Lindydancer interesting — do you have examples of how to do this? I'm still getting used to working in Lisp. thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get and set face attributes using the functions described in the [Face Attributes Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Attribute-Functions.html) section of the Emacs Lisp Reference manual.

E.g.:

```el
(set-face-foreground 'org-agenda-done
                     (face-foreground 'org-agenda-dimmed-todo-face))
```

You can put this in your init file but you have to make sure that the faces are already defined. They are defined in the file `org-faces.el[c]`, so you have to make sure that that file is loaded:

```el
(require 'org-faces)
(set-face-foreground ...)
```

Comment: Where would this code live?

Comment: Edited the answer with the additional info.

Comment: Thanks — I needed the `require` statement that I didn't have before.

Answer (score 2):

The customize interface accepts both [color names and hex values](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Colors.html#RGB-Triplets). You can also press the button for choosing a color, the interface will show you a list of color names with their hex values. You can just search for the color name (`C-s`) of the `Org Agenda Dimmed Todo Face` face foreground color and select it.

Comment: When I click the "choose" button, I'm given a list of colors, but they are from the color spectrum, not colors defined by modes like "org-mode". This means that "Org Agenda Dimmed Todo Face" is not available in that list. Is there some way to get it to show up there?

Comment: It's possible, but it is not easy. Can't you just look up the color name/value using `(face-foreground 'org-agenda-dimmed-todo-face)`? And then search for that...

Comment: I'm using the Dracula theme, and the color listed isn't one of the listed colors, unfortunately.

Comment: Ah well, then you can enter the color manually by typing, or even better, use @NickD's solution...

Answer (score 2):

When defining your face, you can inherit from another face (or even faces). Note that if the original face should change *after* you have defined your face, your face will also change accordingly.

For example:

```
(defface my-extra-warning-face
  '((t :inherit font-lock-warning-face :background "green"))
  "My extra warning face.")
```